# Python Scraping Data From a Search Result

Tags: python, algorithm, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to scrape data from a search result.
This is the search result.

```
https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=12&Center=49.257645%2C-123.123580&LatitudeMax=49.34328&LongitudeMax=-122.84875&LatitudeMin=49.17186&LongitudeMin=-123.39841&view=list&Sort=1-A&PGeoIds=g30_c2b2nw3h&GeoName=Vancouver%2C%20BC&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&Currency=CAD
```

But the data that I need (picture, taxes, description) isn't in the results so I have to visit each link to obtain that data.

I'm not sure what's the best way to accomplish that so I created 2 bots, the first bot scrapes all the links from all the properties and save it in a database and a second bot goes to each link saved in the database and scrapes all the data that I need.

Is there a better and more efficient way of doing that? I couldn't find anything on github that I could use as a template.

Comment: You would either do both the work in same scripts or have 2 scripts the way you have done

Comment: Do you just want to scrape the first one that pops up?